# how to split the body into three parts in react native

Tags: react-native

[just like its displayed in the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/USnEk.jpg)

I just can't split it into three parts I've tried my CSS knowledge but am new to react native ,I will appreciate  your assistance , it seems daunting and SO seems like a good place to seek answers for developers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can nest multiple Views to achieve this.

```
<View style={{flex:1, flexDirection: “row”}}>
  <View style={{flex: 2}}>
    {image1}
  </View>
  <View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: “column”}}>
    {image2}
    {image3}
  </View>
</View>
```